# Nested subroutine calls on MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.data

.text
    .globl __start
    __start:

main:
    jal func
    sll $0,$0,0
    j end

func:
   jal func2
   sll $0,$0,0  
   jr $ra
   sll $0,$0,0

func2:
    jr $ra
    sll $0,$0,0

end
```

I'm using PCSpim. Why it just stops working? What is my error here?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Programmers. This is a direct implementation question, off-topic here but on-topic on Stack Overflow. Let me migrate that for you. Have a pleasant day.

Answer (score 5):

When you do the jump and link in func then you are executing the func2 function and the return address ($ra) is set to the line right after the jump and link (PC+4). Inside the func2 subroutine, you are immediately returning to the position saved in the return address (the sll in func). After the shift you are trying to jump to the return address again which is the sll in func which results in a infinite loop.

In other words, when you do successive subroutine calls, you have to save and restore the return address before and after the subroutine call, respectively.

```
foo:
    #do some functiony stuff
    mov    $s0, $ra    #save return address into s0
    jal    bar         #do the bar subroutine
    mov    $ra, $s0    #restore return address that was saved into s0
    jr     $ra         #jump there

bar:
    #do some more functiony stuff
    jr     $ra
```

You also need to make sure your 'end' is marked as a label (add a colon after it).

Answer (score 3):

After `jal func`, `ra` contains the address that `func` must return to. `jal func2` overwrites `ra`. `func2` then returns to `func1` and `func1` returns to the same address, looping forever.

If a function calls another function, it must preserve `ra` before all calls and restore it after all calls and before returning.

Answer (score 1):

You must **save the return address**

For example:

```
 main:
 ...
 jal func1
 ...

 func1:
    sw $ra, ($sp) # save address   
    ...
    jal func2
    ...
    lw $ra, ($sp) # load
    jr $ra

 func2:
    ....
```