# MIPS: Saving the return address in nested procedures

Tags: assembly, mips

Let's say I have:

```
main:

    // stuff

    jal function_a

function_a:

    // function_a stuff

    jal function_b

    jr $ra

function_b:

    // function_b stuff

    jr $ra
```

From what I understand, main saves the appropriate return address in $ra when it does jal function_a, but then function_a overwrites $ra when it does jal function_b, so obviously $ra needs to be saved at some point. But I can't find anything that actually says what the convention is for doing this. Do I store $ra on the stack while in function_a before calling `jal function_b`? Do I store $ra in an s-register before calling `jal function_b`, and then save that s-register at the beginning of function_b (which I think was implied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702910/nested-subroutine-calls-on-mips))? Something different? Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual practice is to save `$ra` on the stack directly. Storing it in (say) `$s0` doesn't make much sense, since according to normal calling convention `function_a` must also preserve `$s0`, so first you'd have to save `$s0` on the stack to make room for `$ra`. If you don't follow normal calling convention then you can do whatever you want, of course.